# Unity: texture becomes transparent if format 16 bits

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, transparency, sprite

I have a circle.png file. It is just a white (0xFFFFFFFF) circle on a transparent (0x00000000) background.

When I import it to Unity and set Format "Truecolor" everything looks good. But if I set Format "Compressed" or "16 bits" it looks a bit transparent (you can see it on screenshot).

What's wrong?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: nothing is wrong. It is normal.

Comment: @David Thanks for your response.
Can I do anything with it? Could you explain why it is normal?

Answer (score 0):

If your texture contains even one transparent pixel, your whole sprite will be semi-transparent(as in your picture) in Unity if 16 bits or compressed format are selected. It is normal. Only solution to this is you found already, make it true color. You can't do anything with it simply. Maybe, using full opaque texture and get that circle pixels by coding, not easier method i think.